# Swift unable to animate navigation bar button item

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I need some help to translate the `rightBarButtonItem` in the `UINavigationBar`. I have followed [this](https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/how-to-animate-a-bar-button-item-swift/) and also found similar questions which lead me to add the button as a `customView` of a `UIBarButtonItem`, however the code is still not working.

I have created a `UIBarButtonItem` and set a `UIButton` as its custom view.

```
let button: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
    return b
}()

lazy var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

This method is called from `viewDidLoad`

```
func configNavBar() {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

To animate the bar button when some action occurs:

```
func animateRightBarButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1.5,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    guard let customView = self.barButton.customView else {return}
                    var x: CGFloat = customView.transform.tx == 0 ? 100 : 0
                    customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: x, y: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The bar button appears as expect when the view has loaded. I want the button to slide off screen but i have noticed a couple of problems.

The button disappears from the view with no animation when this function is called.
If I `print(x)` (the translate x value) it remains at `100.0` and does not change back to `0` using the ternary operator. Any help appreciated to get this working, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
let bell = UIImage(named: "gift")!
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setBackgroundImage(bell, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showAdd), for: .touchUpInside)
    let bellButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bellButton
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        if let bell = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView {
            let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
            animation.duration = 0.6
            animation.values = [-8.0, 8.0, -8.0, 8.0, -4.0, 4.0, -4.0, 4.0, 0.0 ]
            bell.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanx to @KMI

I improved usability by carrying out the functionality of @KMI 's method in separate helper:

*Swift 5*

**UIBarButtonItem+Helper.swift**

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    typealias AnimationClosure = (_ customView: UIView)->()
    
    private var uniqueCustomViewAnimationKey: String {
        "customViewAnimation"
    }
    
    func animate(with animation: CAAnimation, delay: TimeInterval = 0.5) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) { [weak self] in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            self.customView?.layer.add(animation, forKey: self.uniqueCustomViewAnimationKey)
        }
    }
}
```

And usage in some class:

```
func bellItem() -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bell"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bellItemPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        
    // create custom animation
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    animation.duration = 0.6
    animation.values = [-8.0, 7.0, -6.0, 5.0, -4.0, 3.0, -2.0, 1.0, 0.0 ]

    // applying the animation
    item.animate(with: animation)
        
    return item
}

@objc private func bellItemPressed() {
    // do some stuff when item pressed
}
```